# Entity Framework 6 - Migrations - Adicionar coluna c/ valor default e nomear constraint

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework-6, migrations

Quero adicionar uma coluna do tipo `BIT` a uma tabela existente com um valor default `1` via migrations. O desafio é...temos na empresa um padrão para o nome de `constraints` e não é legal o nome criado automaticamente pelo EF.

Abaixo o código para adicionar a coluna:

```
public override void Up()
{    
   AddColumn("dbo.RODADA_DESAFIO", "FL_STATUS", c => c.Boolean(nullable: false, defaultValue: true));
}
```

**Existe algum parâmetro que eu possa passar no `AddColumn` para definir o nome da `constraint` default ou então alguma outra forma de fazer isso?**

Eu tentei dessa forma:

```
public override void Up()
        {
            AddColumn("dbo.RODADA_DESAFIO", "FL_STATUS", c => c.Boolean(nullable: false))
            Sql("ALTER TABLE RODADA_DESAFIO ADD CONSTRAINT DF_RODADADESAFIO_STATUS DEFAULT (1) FOR FL_STATUS");
        }
```

No entanto aparece o seguinte erro:

```
Column already has a DEFAULT bound to it.
Could not create constraint or index. See previous errors.
```

**NOTA:** A coluna não existe ainda no banco.

Comment: Use o Fluent API.

Comment: Poderia me dar um exemplo?

Comment: Nesse tutorial exemplifica bem.
http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/configure-property-mappings-using-fluent-api.aspx

Comment: Valeu man, no entanto não encontrei nada sobre default constraints nesse tutorial.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pesquisando um pouco descobri que o EF6 não dá suporte para default constraints com nomes customizados via Fluent API. Mas o EF Core sim!!!

> Diego Vega (Program Manager, Entity Framework) commented  ·  May 5,
>   2015 9:05 PM
>
> · **EF7 beta4 supports this** for
>   relational databases with the DefaultExpression() extension method on
>   PropertyBuilder. Usage is something like this:
>
> modelBuilder.Entity()  .Property(p => p.CreatedOn) 
>   .DefaultExpression("CURRENT_TIMESTAMP");
>
> **> The EF team does not have plans to back port the feature to EF6, but
>   we could consider a pull request.**

[Link da fonte - https://data.uservoice.com](https://data.uservoice.com/forums/72025-entity-framework-feature-suggestions/suggestions/2929682-support-database-default-values-in-code-first)

A solução que eu encontrei para essa questão foi:

```
public override void Up()
{
    AddColumn("dbo.RODADA_DESAFIO", "FL_STATUS", c => c.Boolean());
    Sql("UPDATE RODADA_DESAFIO SET FL_STATUS = 1");
    Sql("ALTER TABLE RODADA_DESAFIO ADD CONSTRAINT DF_RODADADESAFIO_STATUS DEFAULT (1) FOR FL_STATUS");
    Sql("ALTER TABLE RODADA_DESAFIO ALTER COLUMN FL_STATUS BIT NOT NULL");
}
```

1. Adicionei a coluna, os valores serão inicialmente nulos (para as
   linhas existentes)
2. Dei update em todas as linhas, setando para o valor default (`BIT 1 /
   true`)
3. Adicionei a `constraint default` com o nome que eu quero
4. Agora consigo alterar a coluna para `non-nullable` sem problemas